# CSS font path is relative to partial.css file, or combined style.css?

Tags: css

I know resource, e.g.: font, image, url is relative to css file that contains it, if you are using relative path, for example:

```
// in partial.css

    @font-face {
    font-family: 'InterstateLight';
        src: url('../../../fonts/Interstate/Interstate-Light.eot');
        src: url('../../../fonts/Interstate/Interstate-Light.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
             url('../../../fonts/Interstate/Interstate-Light.woff') format('woff'),
             url('../../../fonts/Interstate/Interstate-Light.ttf') format('truetype'),
             url('../../../fonts/Interstate/Interstate-Light.svg?#InterstateLight') format('svg');
        font-weight: normal;
        font-style: normal;
    }
```

In my situation, 
many css files in tree like folder structure are concatenated into style.css which is in another folder by Webpack. 
Should font path be relative to the partial.css or combined style.css?

Comment: https://github.com/webpack/css-loader will resolve those with css-loader unless they start with `/` which is not your case.

Comment: I am really glad to know that. Let me try it first~ Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

it is not true !
you can use absolute path too in `url`.

Comment: yep~ I am using relative path here.

Comment: this is not really what OP meant I guess

Comment: I am using absolute path now. i did not say that you can not use relative path i said absolute path work too.i think absolute path is more better and easy.

Answer (score 0):

Use [css-loader](https://github.com/webpack/css-loader) in your `webpack.config.js`

In the following `css-loader` gets applied to all `.css` files.

```
module.exports = {
  module: {
    loaders: [
      { test: /\.css$/, loader: "style-loader!css-loader" },
      { test: /\.png$/, loader: "url-loader?limit=100000" },
      { test: /\.jpg$/, loader: "file-loader" }
    ]
  }
};
```